# How to sort json string by a key value before loop?

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

I would like to sort this kind of json string by itemCategory_title or itemCategory_id before the loop? i tried to use usort but it didn't sort!

could any one tell me how this can be done ?

json string sample data:

```
{ '5123': {
            'tmp': '1', 'name': 'mango', 'abc': 'abcd4 http://mysite/items/1234', 'number': '1123', 'itemCategory_title': 'fruits', 'logo': '2123.png', 'itemCategory_id': '90'
        }, '700': {
            'tmp': '0', 'name': 'cherry', 'abc': 'abcd4 http://mysite/items/1235', 'number': '1124', 'itemCategory_title': 'fruits', 'logo': '2124.png', 'itemCategory_id': '91'
        } }
```

php code:

```
$code2 = stripslashes($_POST['outputtext']);

$clean_str = str_replace("p '","'",$code2);
$clean_str = str_replace('\'', '"', $clean_str);

$data = json_decode($clean_str, true);

//here i want to sort $data by itemCategory_title or itemCategory_id

usort($data, function($a, $b) { //Sort the array using a user defined function
    return $a->itemCategory_id > $b->itemCategory_id ? -1 : 1; //Compare the scores
}); 

foreach( $data as $item ) {
  echo $item['tmp'];
  echo $item['name'];
  echo $item['abc'];
  echo $item['number'];
  echo $item['itemCategory_title'];
  echo $item['log'];
  echo $item['itemCategory_id'];    

?>
<a href="./process.php?tmp=<?php  echo $item['tmp'] ; ?>&name=<?php  echo $item['name']; ?>&abc=<?php  echo $item['abc'] ; ?>&itemCategory_title=<?php  echo $item['itemCategory_title'] ; ?>&log=<?php  echo $item['log'] ; ?>&itemCategory_id=<?php  echo $item['itemCategory_id'] ; ?>"><?php  echo $item['itemCategory_title'] ; ?> </a> <br />
<?

}

?>
```

Comment: Can i ask you why you want to sort a string representation of an object?

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable He's sorting it after he decodes it into an associative array.

Comment: @Barmar but why is he sorting it (don't say object nor array)?

Comment: He wants the HTML to show them in the order of `itemCategory_id`.

Comment: Why don't you `print_r($data)` after your `json_decode`? You'll see your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `usort` function, `->itemCategory_id` should be `['itemCategory_id']`. Since you gave the second argument to `json_decode()`, the JSON objects become PHP associative arrays, not objects.

If you'd turned on error reporting you would have seen the notices about trying to get the properties of a non-object. You got it right when you were echoing them in the `foreach` loop, but not the `usort` comparison function.

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) { //Sort the array using a user defined function
    return $a['itemCategory_id'] > $b['itemCategory_id'] ? -1 : 1; //Compare the scores
});
```

To sort by name within categories, it should be:

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) { //Sort the array using a user defined function
  if ($a['itemCategory_id'] == $b['itemCategory_id']) {
    return $a['name'] > $b['name'] ? 1 : -1;
  } else {
    return $b['itemCategory_id'] - $a['itemCategory_id'];
  }
});
```

This sorts category IDs descending, and names ascending.

Comment: Note that the ternary operation is not mandatory, just use `return $a['itemCategory_id'] - $b['itemCategory_id']` for `ASC` order and switch `$a` and `$b` for DESC order.

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen That works in this case because they're numbers, it wouldn't work in the more general case. And it's not really relevant to the problem in the code.

Comment: Thanks all for replies.Barmar it sorted correctly now. If i want to sort all items that got same itemCategory_id alphabetically do i need to push those items with same itemCategory_id to another array then sort ? or is there any easier method ?

Comment: You add a check for that to the `usort` function. `if ($a['itemCategory_id'] == $b['itemCategory_id']) { return `$a['name'] > $b['name'] ? -1 : 1; } else { ... }`

Comment: i tried that but didn't sort it the way i want it. This is the way i want my final data be sorted:apple (fruits=>itemCategory_id=12)
bannana(fruits=>itemCategory_id=12)

bmw(cars=>itemCategory_id=11)
ford(cars=>itemCategory_id=11) i want all items that have same itemcategory for example id=11 be sort a-z not mixed or z-a

Comment: I can't figure out how you're sorting there. But the general answer is that you test the most significant attribute first, if that's equal you test the next most significant, if that's equal you test the next one, and so on.

Comment: Why do you have category 12 before category 11?

Comment: To get them in a-z order, use `? 1 : -1` in the `name` test, not `? -1 : 1`.

Comment: your first code sorts correctly by category id but i want to sort further by name for all items that got same category id but it missed up the whole sorting :usort($data, function($a, $b) {
if ($a['itemCategory_id'] == $b['itemCategory_id']) 
{ 
return $a['name'] > $b['name'] ? 1 : -1; 

}
});

Comment: Many thanks it worked correctly . In case if i want to reverse the sort category id from small to big what should i do ? your edited code lists it from big to small .

Comment: Change the order of the parameters to `-`.

Comment: I did it from big to small because that's the order that your original code does.

Comment: It's also the order in your comment, you had category 12 before category 11.